# What functions do we need to solve linear second order differential equations with polynomial coeficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, integrable-systems

**Disclaimer:** I have posted this question on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408130/what-functions-do-we-need-to-solve-linear-second-order-differential-equations-wi) following the instructions of [this topic](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638).

---

I'm now trying to understand how can a ordinary differential equation be tested to decide if it's integrable or not. Recently I become aware of the Painlevé property and start to read the following paper by Robert Conte:

[The Painlevé Approach to Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-1532-5_3)

In section 2.1, he states:

"A very deep result of L. Fuchs, Poincaré and Painlevé is that the class of first order ODEs...
...defines one and only one function... ...the elliptic function introduced earlier by Weierstrass..."

**My initial question is:**
Does this means that the solutions of any integrable first order ODE can by expressed by elementary functions and the Weierstrass elliptic function?

I know that many functions that are solutions to second order ODE (Exponentials, [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Special_cases), hypergeometric functions, [Airy functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAi/introductions/Airys/ShowAll.html)...) can be expressed by generalized hypergeometric series.

**My main question is:**
Are there some set of functions such that all solutions to linear second order ODE, with polynomial coeficients, can be expressed with? (may be: rational functions, exponentials and generalized hypergeometric series) If yes, where can I find a comprehensive list?